# DI a post action interface or raise an event?

Tags: design, object-oriented-design

I got a class A that creates an object of type B and persists it on a database.

The class B can be created in several ways so it receives an interface ICreator so it can create the object. Problem is that now I found myself needing to do something after the object is persisted on the database. This is a very specific case: I need to create fourth object that refences the type B object, for this I need the primary key of the object on the database. I can't honestly say if this kind of post-action is going to be needed for future cases so I was wondering the best way to handle this.

At first I thought of creating a postaction interface and invoke it from object, something that would go like this:

```
    class ClassA
    {
        public void CreateObjectAndPersistIt(ICreator creator, IPostAction postAction)
        {
            var classBObject = creator.CreateObject();
            PersistObject(classBObject);
            if (postAction != null)
            { postAction.DoSomeStuff(classBObject); }
        }
    }
```

But I also thought of raising an event on PersistObject called "ObjectBCreated" and let the one that asked for the object to be created and persisted care about whatever comes next (if anything). Right now I'm more inclined to go with the second solution for I find it more flexible.

Is there a third option that makes more sense or maybe the first option is superior in a way that I'm missing right now?

Comment: Why would class A even care about the existence of a fourth object persisted after B?  Shouldn't the caller of the class A method be dealing with whatever comes next?

Comment: That's what I thought when I came up with the idea of raising the event and let the handler do whatever it needs to do. I take it that you agree that the event thing is a good idea?

Comment: No.  What do you *normally* do when you need to call method X, but after you need to do Y?  You call X, and *then* you call Y.  You don't try to setup a complicated event system.  The class responsible for *wanting* an instance of class B (and calls method of class A) should be the same that would *want* the object that references A, right?  If that's not the case, then the question should be *why not*?  In other words, you're trying to detach creation of B (class A) from its subsequent dependency of class B, when the *caller of A* should be responsible for this..

Comment: I got several instances where classA is called an only in one case that after creating objectB further action is needed. It is from a diferrent entry point. If it was as straight forward as after step1 go to step2 then there would be no question.

Comment: Okay, well that was my question.  Why wouldn't it *be* straightforward as that?  The "right" approach is to fix the caller again, but lacking that, any other solution is going to be ugly I'm afraid.

Comment: Because there are several callers and, right now, only one does something with the created object after it is created. The rest of them just need The object created and forget about it. I also think that is likely that some new callers are going to exist on the future that might need to do something with the object after it is created.

Comment: Just differentiate this particular case from others where you only need to create the object, and in that case, just call both methods rather than just the one.

Comment: Then that'd be the first solution because the caller never gets the reference on classB. Either that or have CreateObjectAndPersistIt to return the classB reference. But since nothing is done with it most of the time it feels kinda silly to me.